# I need a true random number generator web service

Tags: web-development, web-applications, web-services, random

Random.org provides 200k free random bits (only 6250 32-bit integers!) from the analog world ([cf.](https://www.random.org/analysis/#visual)) per IP per day.

Does anyone know of an alternative web service that provides more on-demand  random bits per day?

(paying is OK as long as the price is "within expectations" of 1000×1024bits per usd cent) (random.org's paid service charges 100× this price)

Comment: The bigger question is "why" do you need a "truly" random number generator?

Comment: A true random generator in pure software does not exist.  You can get close, at the end of the day, it won't be truely random.

Comment: For anyone interested in the theoric part of software / hardware TRNG, check this : http://www.cryptography.com/public/pdf/IntelRNG.pdf

Comment: And why does it need to be a web service, instead of a simple random number generator running on your PC, or as part of your webapp?

Comment: What do you need it for? If it's a game or something, then pseudo-random is normally good enough. If it's cryptography, they you shouldn't use a web service. You need to explain what it's for before we can point you to viable solutions.

Comment: Here ya go! `[webservice] public int GetRandomNumber() { return 4; // rfc 1149.5 }`. Credit: [xkcd.com/221](http://xkcd.com/221)

Comment: Technically, there's no sufficient means to determine if a set of numbers is random.  Numbers could always be 0 and it could technically happen, albeit extremely improbable.  To those of you who say that that could never happen, I say, what are the chances that a random number generator will generate the exact number 20993429237112734772201092292773?  Yes, in fact, extremely improbable.

Comment: I'm not thinking of a scenario in which you'd need that.  Using anything publicly available as a cryptographic key or one-time pad is a Bad Idea, far less secure than just using AES-256 with key exchange by asymmetric communication.  You can get real random-number generators that work on principles like thermal noise and radioactive decay and either use the numbers locally or put them out as a stream to your clients, and that should serve most purposes.  You didn't say "free" web service, so you presumably can afford your own.

Comment: @Neil:  There is no way to examine a set of numbers to determine randomness.  There are ways to generate numbers that are random, according to our understanding of physics.  Radioactive decay is believed to be completely random, and all attempts at finding some sort of theoretical predictability have failed.

Comment: @John R. Strohm please read Ramhound's reply. It tells you why

Comment: I would like to point out that it's sad when the XKCD answer with a 50/50 vote split is the 'best' (voted, as well as written quality) answer of the lot.

Comment: @Craige:  I think it relates to the quality of the question.  The OP has odd requirements that make no sense I've been able to figure out, and hasn't explained them despite being asked.  Usually, this means that the OP is doing things in a screwy way, and would benefit from a wider approach to the problem.  Without a better question, we can't have good answers.

Comment: @Pacerier: PCs have facilities to measure random noise in the environment, you can get good enough random number generation.

Comment: @Ramhound Exactly why I'm asking for something beyond the capabilities of software

Comment: 9....9.....9... prove its not random

Comment: On-line casinos do in fact need a steady supply of truly random numbers.  However, getting them from somewhere else that's publicly available is a Bad Idea.  On-line gambling sites are magnets for people who want to exploit them, and they'll need to generate their own securely.

Comment: Would a prebuilt unit be useful?  I just googled "hardware random number generator usb", and got several links.  They aren't cheap by hobbyist standards, but several hundred euros is likely to be reasonable if making a commercial site.

Comment: @David Thornley . I believe that's debatable. Anyway I'm merely stating an example.

Comment: @Glenn Nelson I can't. But i can prove its not a generator.

Comment: **If you need to have an extended discussion on this question can you take it to chat please.**

Comment: @Pacerier:  The problem with asking for something specific without reason given is that it may not have a clear use in real life.  I haven't thought of a good one myself (too insecure for crypto or casinos, overkill for games or most Monte Carlo simulations or stochastic algorithms).  If you're just curious, you don't need to explain being unable to build a hardware one.  If you have an app with specific needs, we can help better if we know what the needs are.

Comment: I agree with @DavidThornley. I can't think of any question to which a webservice RNG is the answer. So I'd like the OP to come up with such a problem, since I've been thinking about that problem for a long time.

Comment: "I can't. But i can prove its not a generator." How can you prove it's not a generator? And decent generator will pass any randomness test you throw at it with the same likelihood as a true RNG.

Comment: @CodeInChaos you seemed to miss what I'm trying to say. I'm saying I can prove it **is not** a generator (Glenn can't possible be a generator or a service i can call), not that those results are not **from** a generator

Comment: @CodeInChaos My problem is that I need a non-deterministic random number for my game. It's an investment game that requires true random numbers for a good simulation. A deterministic algorithm is just not good enough for a real simulation you see.

Comment: @David Thornley My problem is that I need a non-deterministic random number for my game. It's an investment game that requires true random numbers for a good simulation. A deterministic algorithm is just not good enough for a real simulation you see.

Comment: no I still don't see. What difference would a PRNG make compared to a real RNG? (I'm talking about a good PRNG not the default function built into c). There are even PRNGs for which it has been proven that distinguishing it from true randomness implies you being able to factor large numbers.

Comment: @CodeInChaos you'll have to agree with me that there are differences between the best PRNG and a real RNG

Comment: Excuse me sir, would you like to buy some integers? We stock only the finest free-range, artisinal integers.

Comment: Say someone builds you a web service that outputs random numbers but says they can't give you the implementation details (patent protected). How would you go about determining if the numbers output are truly number and not just output from /dev/random? You may be able to tell if they were using a "bad" PRNG but I'd think you'd run into problems distinguishing a "good" PRNG from a true RNG.

Comment: @uesp You'll be surprised at how transparent things are. Often they do tell you exactly what they are doing and even with pictures (its nice to brag about having this kind of hardware). In fact that's what the people at http://random.org are doing. in fact, Say you use any third party web service (mashup). How would you go about determining that service is doing as it says it will? Trust is a very important factor here. Without that mashups would be useless.

Comment: "you'll have to agree with me that there are differences between the best PRNG and a real RNG" The differences are irrelevant for almost every use. There is a difference if somebody can break the crypto your PRNG is based on, but that's extremely unlikely and even it somebody does it's most likely just the NSA who has better things to do than attacking your PRNG.

Comment: The second difference is that if you get the internal state of the PRNG you can predict future random numbers(at least until the next entropy injection). But that requires gaining access to your server(probably even root access) and in that case you've lost anyways.

Comment: @CodeInChaos exactly. You've just answered your own question 7 posts above.

Comment: I still don't see a single case where there is a practical problem with a PRNG in which you don't have the same problem with a true PRNG. A compromised server is a game over in both cases, and a cryptographic breakthrough is more likely to break your SSL connection to the webservice than to break your local generator. So no I didn't answer my own question. Since none of the minor differences presents a disadvantage for the PRNG.

Comment: @CodeInChaos did you happen to read my second edit 12 hours ago? (I've no idea why you are talking about compromised servers / cryptographic breakthroughs / breaking my SSL connection (am I even using SSL?)). A true random number generator though related to cryptography is completely a different entity altogether

Comment: I'm talking about these situations because those are the only situations where there are any observable differences between a true RNG and a good PRNG. The quality of pseudo random numbers of a good generator is by itself good enough for every non security related use.

Comment: @CodeInChaos so why are they not good enough for online casinos which is not a security related use but a money related one

Comment: I think from a purely technical point of view they are good enough for online casinos. There are mathematic proofs for some generators that the random numbers are extremely good. There might be legal reasons since perhaps some regulations require true random numbers. And perhaps publicity reasons. Because claiming "We use true random numbers" sounds better to uneducated users than "We use a cryptographic PRNG".

Comment: @CodeInChaos good you've just proved yourself wrong 3 posts above

Comment: VIA processors have extra hardware for this kind of things.  A simple single-board VIA computer with some Linux software might be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Maybe this one.

http://qrng.physik.hu-berlin.de/

From the site:

> We provide a new quantum random number
>   generator (QRNG) based on the quantum
>   randomness of photon arrival times. It
>   promises provable and long term
>   statistical quality, speed as well as
>   affordability. Our design creates a
>   new quality in the sense that it
>   offers substantially higher bit rates
>   than previous solutions available to
>   the public. This has become possible
>   by exploiting most recent photon
>   timing instrumentation and
>   state-of-the-art data processing in
>   hardware.
>
> In addition to providing high speed
>   (up to 150 Mbits/s over USB), the
>   post-processing algorithm applied to
>   the raw data is based on solid
>   predictions from information theory
>   which guarantee conservation of
>   randomness. This allows for the use of
>   the delivered random numbers in
>   unconditionally secure encryption
>   schemes.
>   [...]
>   **Access Policies**
>   None of the served data is delivered more than once, neither to a single user nor across > independent users. Using the service is free of charge, but requires registration.

Comment: (0.o) ?! egad! I thought it was a joke, but no it really does exist :)  (+1) great find

Comment: -1 for poor quality answer. This could very well be a great solution, but you have provided no details on the link/service, and I don't care to read the entire link for a summary. When an answer on P.SE requires a link, please provide a summary of the solution you are linking to. I will consider removing my downvote if you revise your answer.

Comment: @Craige, sheesh its a good link, why repeat whats on the website

Comment: @NimChimpsky - Why? Because that is how you write a quality answer on P.SE. ba__friend should have posted a brief description of the service for those reading over this question. Perhaps a quick explanation/quote as to how the service generates it's random numbers.

Comment: @Craige I updated the post with an excerpt from the site.

Comment: @ba__friend there is no way to call that service through HTTP at all (correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: @NimChimpsky: Because linkrot happens.

Comment: @Pacerier what do you mean you can't call it through HTTP? You obtain chunks of random data through HTTP(S) from that service..

Comment: @ba__friend I keep getting 403 forbidden from my request. Did someone actually tested it to work?

Comment: @Pacerier You should probably contact the people behind that site for support.

Comment: @Pacerier please read the site carefully it's all there. "Using the service is free of charge, but requires registration." and "Login required to download files"

Comment: @ba__friend yep i've definitely got that part. In fact I've read every single word on that entire domain but still can't get it to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041632/my-post-request-to-https-qrng-physik-hu-berlin-de-failed-why

Answer (score 33):

What you are asking for is Holy water, and you are rejecting the suggestion that you use regular water. The only reason for preferring Holy water over water is religious. There are simple, randomly-seeded PRNGs that cannot be distinguished from true physical randomness by any known process. And these systems *are* non-deterministic.

A real-world computer has several sources of true physical randomness. For example, a modern x86 CPU has a 'TSC' which measures the instruction cycle count (and thus, indirectly, the time to a resolution of a billionth of a second or so).

You can capture the TSC when a network packet arrives. The low bits of the TSC will depend on the precise offset between the crystal oscillator that times the network interface and the crystal oscillator that runs the CPU. This is dependent on microscopic zone temperature variations in the two quartz crystals that are believed to be truly random.

Similarly, you can capture the TSC when data arrives from the hard drive. The low bits are dependent on turbulent airflow shearing between the hard drive surface and the case. This is also believed to be truly random.

Well-known algorithms, such as the one the Linux kernel uses (developed by Theodore Ts'o based on the work of M. Matsumoto and Y. Kurita) use the avalanche effect to convert a few unpredictable bits into a much larger number. The only differences between the outputs of these algorithms (assuming they are properly seeded by TSC data) and the output of true physical randomness is religious -- no known method can distinguish these outputs. There is no test that one will pass and the other will fail.

I have developed random number generators for online casino use that have achieved independent certification. These methods are the ones used in the real world.

Comment: +1 for the common sense, the interesting examples and the nice holy water metaphor!

Comment: Super +1. Reminds me of [How We Learned to Cheat at Online Poker: A Study in Software Security](http://www.cigital.com/papers/download/developer_gambling.php)

Comment: @David, Hi, mind elaborating on the story "I have developed random number generators for online casino use"..?

Comment: It's not that interesting. An online casino hired me to develop an RNG for them, I did, and it was certified by TST, an Australian certification firm.

Answer (score 13):

I still don't understand why a cryptographic PRNG isn't good enough for your problem. A defining property of a crypto-PRNG is that it's not possible(with reasonable amounts of hardware) to distinguish its output from a true RNG.

This means it is good enough for any kind of simulation or application I can think of, apart from generation cryptographic keys or initializing the crypto PRNG itself(it obviously needs a few hundred bits of true entropy to get started).

On the other hand webservice RNGs can't be used for crypto either since

1. You can't prove they are actually a true PRNG since you can't distinguish their output from a PRNG
2. You need to trust the operator of the service
3. The random data is transmitted to you over lower security channel. An attacker who can break a PRNG can break SSL too.

So I can't think of a single use where one would prefer a webservice RNG over a good PRNG. If you truly need real and secure random numbers I see no alternative to building hardware yourself.

Comment: Yes i can't prove the output to be truly random. but its not that hard to trust it http://www.random.org/statistics/. You seem to assume security is one of my requirement but its not. I need a random number fullstop. Not a random and secure number. (If an attacker wants to eavesdrop feel free, it wouldn't hurt)

Comment: It's not hard to trust a PRNG for which it has been mathematically been proven that distinguishing it from a true RNG requires solving *very* hard mathematical problems.

Comment: @CodeInChaos is an online casino a very hard mathematical problem? It isn't, but it requires that kind of true randomness don't you think so?

Comment: I see no *technical* reasons why a good PRNG occasionally received a hundred bits of true entropy shouldn't be enough for even an online casino. There might be *legal* reasons, but I assume in that case you need generate your true randomness locally since this gives you better chances of proving that you're using true random numbers.

Comment: @CodeInChaos not unless you're using a web service which is specifically built for this purpose. Your local true random number generator VS the true random number generator over 10 other online casino sites use

Comment: +1 I totally agree with you. If you are creating a game that needs to generate realistic random data then you are better off with a PRNG than a truly random number generator. Firstly there is a mathematical proof that it produces statistically random data fitted to a probability distribution. Secondly you can choose that probability distribution. Thirdly you can test your application deterministically. Fourthly you can choose the seed at start up so that it never behaves the same way twice. Personally I think the OP doesn't actually understand what randomness means, or why he needs it.

Answer (score 5):

Several years ago you could call SGI's [lavarand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lavarand) which generated random numbers by using the current blob shape and postion of a lava lamp being watched by a webcam.

Though it's gone now you can easily create your own generator with a webcam and the open source code from the fine folks at **[LavaRnd](http://www.lavarnd.org/)** (EDIT: down for some time now. [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/%2a/http://www.lavarnd.org/) [Sourceforge Project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lavarnd/)). It turns out that you don't need the lava lamp at all: the noise picked up by the CCD while the webcam is sealed in a light-proof container is a great source for generating cryptographically sound random numbers.

(I know this isn't a service you can use now, but because it used to be, because it was so cool, and because you can create a nearly free one very easily, I figured it was worthy of being an answer.)

Comment: but surely over time the "random" noise generated by the webcam would fit a normal distribution? I don't know would like it clarified?

Comment: @Darknight:  What does the distribution have to do with randomness?  It's possible to generate deterministic sequences to match any distribution, and it's possible for random numbers to fit any distribution.

Comment: @Darknight As David notes, whether or not the numbers eventually fit a normal distribution doesn't affect the randomness. If you're interested in what is required to make a random number generator cryptographically sound (or crypto strong), the LavaRnd guys have a ton of "stat nerd" info and links on their site, along with how they relate to LavaRnd.

Comment: Seriously there's no way to create one easily Matthew. How exactly do you define easy?

Comment: @Pacerier You're right that "easy" is a matter of perspective. This method is easy if you have access to your server and finding a suitable webcam doesn't take long -- a $10 "buy it now" on ebay, say. That leaves attaching the camera; downloading, compiling, and running the free software; and adding a call to the service in your code. Not trivial, but pretty easy, extremely inexpensive, and provides an unlimited number of requests.

Answer (score 1):

Open a TCP connection to any host/port and count the number of nanoseconds it takes. There's your random number.

Comment: I hope this isn't how you are actually generating random numbers.

Comment: The point of my (mildly sarcastic) answer is that the entropy in the time it takes packets to travel is worth a lot more than a "random" number whose entropy you trust to a third-party server.

Comment: In fact, delegating the task to a third-party is definitely more trustworthy. That's the reason why no one decides to roll out their own algorithm to perform cryptography

Comment: @Pacerier:  Nobody intelligent writes their own crypto, unless they're an expert.  That's different from sending your plaintext to a web service and getting ciphertext back.  Similarly, you probably don't want to try to design your own quantum randomness system, but getting random numbers shipped to you through HTTP isn't reliable.

Comment: @David Thornley +1 for correct analogy. But you see, the alternative (building one myself) is just not possible

Comment: @Pacerier But you still haven't shown why the alternative of using a local PRNG with occasional entropy injection(from local entropy sources) is not possible.

Comment: @CodeInChaos i need a good simulation for my economics/investment game. Perhaps we can argue on the definition of "good" in another thread? This thread has a clear question, and I've provided my current situation as requested. why are you posting stuff like "Hey you don't need a merce benz, a bike will do fine for you" when I've clearly stated a bike is not fine and when your posts doesn't guide the question towards its answer at all?

Comment: @Pacerier: trust me on this: you don't need genuine random numbers for economics simulations. A good pseudo- (or quasi-, if you care about the even distribution) random generator will be enough. The problems lie elsewhere (for example: you want the numbers to be uncorrelated in many dimensions -- how do you know that the webservice you use even bothers to check how their numbers fill a 20-dimensional space?).

Comment: Now that I know what OP wants, here it the best answer I know of for evaluating different PRNGs: http://guru.multimedia.cx/category/pseudo-random-number-generators/

Comment: @quant_div read the comments in my question. You'll be surprised at how transparent things are. Often they do tell you exactly what they are doing and even with pictures (its nice to brag about having this kind of hardware). In fact that's what the people at random.org are doing. in fact, Say you use any third party web service (mashup). How would you go about determining that service is doing as it says it will? Trust is a very important factor here. Without that mashups would be useless.

Answer (score 1):

here is another quantum based generator, with a rest api no less :

http://photonics.anu.edu.au/qoptics/Research/qrng.php

> Researchers at the ANU are generating true random numbers from a
>   physical quantum source. We do this by splitting a beam of light into
>   two beams and then measuring the power in each beam.  Because light is
>   quantised, the light intensity in each beam fluctuates about the mean.
>   Those fluctuations, due ultimately to the quantum vacuum, can be
>   converted into a source of random numbers.